# Jenkins installation issue on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

Please help me in Jenkins installation on Ubuntu 20.04 Server.

I have Followed below Setups to install Jenkins Server on Ubuntu but getting errors ......
https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/

> Error coming in Fresh Jenkins installation again and again.
> https://prnt.sc/1qDSnFUedJhN
> https://prnt.sc/TjVAIxiJTPeB

Comment: I assume you've already tried the standard solutions like rebooting, and trying to delete the package. Did you try either of the `systemctl` or `journalctl` commands that were printed out? They might indicate more specifically what the problem is.

Comment: Yes i have checked

Comment: Hi ,
i  found the solution of this issue.

i have added in /etc/profile file  "export JAVA_HOME and export PATH "  in the last than after my Jenkins issue has been fixed.
https://prnt.sc/-9xNkMBF2Zmn

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: *Hi , i found the solution of this issue.* -- then please add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so others can know how to solve your problem.  Thanks!